# WordPress Theme footer remove after use Autoptimizer plugins

Tags: plugins

I have used Automizer plugins to speed up WordPress websites. Speed increased but my theme footer disabled, with slider javascript removed. How do I get this footer and slider JavaScript back?

Anyone can help me with this problem. Thanks in advance for the advice.

Comment: Maybe there is a php error somewhere preventing the bottom code of your page from loading. Enabled debugging and check your error logs.

Comment: I would try a different caching plugin, I have had other problems with Autoptimizer (I couldn't find 'Automizer' but I assume that is what you are using) and strange output after using their compression. Alternatively, there are many compression options for JS that would probably need to be checked. Or just turn off JS compression and just use it for CSS and HTML for now.

Also, if your theme is structured so that CSS & JS resources are in subfolders Autoptimizer may not compress properly. At least those were some problems that I had.